# set intersection from list containing data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, intersection

I have a list where each element in the list is a data frame.

```
> df.list[[1]]
      Change       Diff          VarName
1  10.433354  5.311973e-02         a
2   4.587958  1.517604e-02         b
3   4.566829  1.082679e-02         c
4   4.464458  1.345807e-02         d
5   4.146909  7.758011e-03         e
6   4.141556  1.416043e-02         f

> df.list[[2]]
      Change       Diff          VarName
1  12.443354  5.311973e-02         j
2   3.587958  1.517604e-02         k
3   4.566829  1.082679e-02         a
4   4.464458  1.345807e-02         b
5   3.146909  7.758011e-03         d
6   2.141556  1.416043e-02         e
```

Length of my list is 10 where there are 10 data frames. each data frame has 30 items. I want to `intersect` each data frame's top 25 with another and finally get most common items in all data frames.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
df1 <- df.list[[1]]$VarName
df2 <- df.list[[2]]$VarName
df3 <- df.list[[3]]$VarName
df4 <- df.list[[4]]$VarName

intersect(intersect(intersect(df1,df2), df3), df4)
```

Is there away to do this using `dplyr` or any other tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `Reduce` in base R:

```
ls <- vector("list", 10)
for (i in 1:10) ls[[i]] <- head(df.list[[i]]$VarName, 25)
Reduce(intersect, ls)
```

Or a one-liner code:

```
Reduce(intersect, lapply(df.list, function(x) head(x$VarName, 25)))
```

Comment: In one line, `Reduce(function(x, y) intersect(x, head(y$varname, 25)), dfList, init=letters)` where the init value contains the universe of possibilities.

Comment: Thanks @Imo, in the mean time I was thinking about a one-liner code which is now added.